# What should be done when OP replaced his MCVE with the text of his homework question?

Tags: discussion, homework

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831996/its-about-displaying-queue-elements-in-c-sharp-with-different-wait-times-seconds/57832105?noredirect=1#comment102093653_57832105), the poster asks what I think is a genuine question with some explanation and a short snippet triggering a bunch of answers. Then, OP erased his snippet and replaced it with a good old text straight from an exercise.

[image]

What should be do when OP replaced his MCVE with the text of his homework question?

Note: I voted to close it but I think about retracting my vote.

Comment: The 'snippet' is an empty envelope.  A burger bun with no patty.  It was probably given out with the question.  The question is the essence of unwelcoming and so, in traditional SO fashion, it gets answers:(

Comment: I would roll back. It invalidates the answers or at least makes the answers seem out of context

Comment: @MartinJames I did find strange for a junior developer to use a Queue instead of a List. It did not stop me to answer too...

Comment: You should probably have voted to close the question in first place instead of answering it because it lacked any description of what the problem is or what op asks about.

Comment: @BDL My understanding was that OP was asking how to have two values in a collections (one for printing and one for sleeping). It seems quite clear to me.

Comment: @aloisdg: Then why does op have an empty and unused `MyQueue` class? Or why is Sleep commented out? The point is, we are just guessing what op needs, expect for a complete solution to his task.

Comment: @BDL empty class MyQueue -> to build its own queue with two items per slot. Sleep commented out-> no need to wait during debug time. At the end you are right, this is all wild guessing.